# Django migrate ValueError: too many values to unpack

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-migrations

Calling `python manage.py migrate` results in the following error for the auth table. I've tried deleting my DB and all migrations to start from scratch, not sure where the issue is coming from. Django version is 4.1

```
$ python manage.py migrate                                                                                     
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: admin, auth, contenttypes, generator, sessions
Running migrations:
  Applying auth.0001_initial...Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "<redacted>/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 446, in execute_from_command_lin
e
    utility.execute()
  File "<redacted>/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 440, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "<redacted>/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 402, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "<redacted>/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 448, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "<redacted>/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 96, in wrapped
    res = handle_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "<redacted>/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 349, in handle
    post_migrate_state = executor.migrate(
  File "<redacted>/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 135, in migrate
    state = self._migrate_all_forwards(
  File "<redacted>/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 167, in _migrate_all_forwards
    state = self.apply_migration(
  File "<redacted>/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 255, in apply_migration
    migration_recorded = True
  File "<redacted>/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/schema.py", line 39, in __exit__
    self.connection.check_constraints()
  File "<redacted>/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 289, in check_constraints
    for column_name, (
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

Comment: Have you upgraded the verison to 4.1 from previous version?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2) in Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37244808/valueerror-too-many-values-to-unpack-expected-2-in-django)

Comment: @SunderamDubey no I've started this project with 4.1 haven't upgraded. And it shouldn't be an issue with any of my custom models, its just trying to create the django auth table `Applying auth.0001_initial`

Answer (score 1):

There is some issue with Django 4.1. Uninstall django and reinstall it with 4.0. This solved it for me.

```
pip uninstall django

pip install django==4.0
```